# Passing a variable to the Find method from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched through your forum as well as many others for an answer to my question. Every time I get close to what I need; but each time I fall short of getting my need fulfilled.
I am working with two open workbooks; one having a list of phone numbers and data related to incoming calls; the other related to the phone numbers and the user name for the phone number.
On the first workbook I have separated the list into groups by phone number with a blank row between the groups. I then go through the list and capture the phone number to be used in a “Find” in the second workbook, so I can match the phone number and capture the user name to take back to the first workbook and paste into the blank row below the associated group.
My problem is that no matter how I modify my find, I cannot get it to perform properly and select the phone number in the second workbook. I have finally managed to get it to process with no errors, but now it will not do a search. Here is my VB code; if you can help me with this I would really appreciate it.

## If I can get the first search to work, I plan to modify that into a loop to continue throughout the first workbook until the end of the worksheet.

```
Sub Test_Find_Match_Data()
'
' Test_Find_Match_Data Macro
'
Dim Phone_Number As String, _
        Called_Number As Long, _
        Find_Test As Range

    Range("A1").Select

    Cells.Find(What:="called number", _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select

    Phone_Number = ActiveCell.Value

    Selection.Copy

    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext

    Range("A1").Select

        If Find_Test Is Nothing Then

        ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1, _
               ColumnOffset:=0).Activate

            If ActiveCell.Value <> Phone_Number Then

                Set Find_Test = Cells.Find(What:=Phone_Number, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)

                    Selection.Copy

                    Range("A1").Select

            ActiveWindow.ActivateNext

            End If

        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How are the phone numbers stored in each workbook - as formatted text or as true numbers?

Comment: The phone numbers are stored as true numbers, formatted as phone numbers.

Comment: Try declaring Phone number as Long

Comment: when I declare Phone_number as Long, I get an error on the line "Phone_Number = ActiveCell.Value" - "Run-time error '6': Overflow"

Comment: Oh - you probably need a Double then.

Comment: Changing the declaration to Double, goes back to what I was getting to begin with. As I step through the Sub, I watch each step to see what it is doing. I notice that the value for the Phone_Number has been established properly from the first workbook. When I switch to the second workbook, I then move to the column that contains the phone numbers, and activate the first cell below the header, before I initiate the Find. The statement with the "Find" gets skipped over as if it does not want to do anything, then it goes to the next command. It has not moved off of the initial phone number cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `Phone_Number = ActiveCell.Value` with `Phone_Number = ActiveCell.Text`

Comment: I changed the entry "ActiveCell.Value" to "ActiveCell.Text" as you suggested, and had the same result.

Comment: The problem I am still having is when I am on the second workbook, the "Find" statement does not move from the current cell to locate the value I am trying to put in as the criteria.